# Re-rendering React component when I call useState hook

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, tensorflow.js

I have a problem with the re-rendering React component when I call `useState()` hook inside `image.onload()`. I'm expecting the component to be re-render once after I call `setClassificationResult`, but of some reason, it's re-rendering all the time, like I have some infinite loop. Here is my code:

```
const ImageClassification = React.memo(function() {
  const [isModelLoaded, setModelLoaded] = useState(false);
  const [uploadedFile, setUploadedFile] = useState();
  const [classifier, setClassifier] = useState();
  const [classificationResult, setClassificationResult] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    async function modelReady() {
      setClassifier(
        await MobileNet.load().then(model => {
          setModelLoaded(true);
          return model;
        })
      );
    }

    modelReady();
  }, []);

  function onDrop(acceptedFiles: File[]) {
    setUploadedFile(acceptedFiles);
  }

  function prepareImage(inputFile: File) {
    const image = new Image();
    let fr = new FileReader();

    fr.onload = function() {
      if (fr !== null && typeof fr.result == "string") {
        image.src = fr.result;
      }
    };
    fr.readAsDataURL(inputFile);

    image.onload = async function() {
      const tensor: Tensor = tf.browser.fromPixels(image);
      classifier.classify(tensor).then((result: any) => {
        // Crazy re-rendering happens when I call this hook.
        setClassificationResult(result);
        console.log(result);
      });
      console.log("Tensor" + tensor);
    };
  }

  const { getRootProps, getInputProps, isDragActive } = useDropzone({ onDrop });

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      {!isModelLoaded ? (
        <CircularProgress />
      ) : (
        <div {...getRootProps()}>
          <input {...getInputProps()} />
          {isDragActive ? (
            <p>Drop the files here.. </p>
          ) : (
            <p>Drag 'n' drop some files here, or click to select files</p>
          )}
          {uploadedFile &&
            uploadedFile.map((item: File) => {
              prepareImage(item);
              return classificationResult
                ? classificationResult.map((result: any) => {
                    return (
                      <ClassificationResult
                        className={result.className}
                        probability={result.probability}
                      />
                    );
                  })
                : null;
            })}
        </div>
      )}
    </React.Fragment>
  );
});

export default ImageClassification;
```

Any idea of how to avoid that crazy re-rendering?

Comment: component will re-render if you update the state. what actually you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm expecting the component to be re-render once,  but it's re-rendering all the time, not only once. What I'm trying to do is to set classification result to `classificationResult` and then to render result in the component. I will update the question also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a **lifecycle issue** with your component, as it call `prepareImage(item)` from your `return` html value. This means you will call this function at each rendering which is why it create some infinite-loop crazy re-redering.

You need to **rethink your algorithm** and move it to **a better location**. A good solution would to only prepareImage `onDrop event` so it is done only once.

```
function onDrop(acceptedFiles: File[]) {
    setUploadedFile(acceptedFiles);
    acceptedFiles.forEach(file => {
        prepareImage(file);
    });
}
```

Then maybe store in state an **array of Image** which should be dislayed and be prepared .

Comment: Thanks, it makes a lot of sense :)